# Как отправить POST запрос через Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, retrofit

Возможно, сейчас будет задан глуповатый вопрос, т.к. я новичок в Java-программировании и в разработке под Android в целом, так что, хочу заранее извиниться.
Мне нужно получить данные из API с помощью Retrofit 2.0. Я смотрел всякие обучалки в интернете, более того, у меня даже получилось получить список репозиторев Github. Но я не понимаю, как получать не список, а что-то одно, конкретное. Например, на данный момент мне нужно отправить методу /login параметры E-Mail и Password, чтобы получить токен авторизации. Но, как уже было сказано выше, я не могу разобраться, как :(
Если бы кто-то смог мне хоть как-нибудь помочь, я был бы очень благодарен. Не прошу писать за меня код, прошу помочь разобраться в этом всём.

Comment: На какой сервер Вы хотите отправить запрос?

Comment: Вы не переживайте, я Вам помогу, всё когда-то нужно начинать впервые. Приготовьтесь, нужно будет создать несколько java-модулей, где-то 3-4. И можете также установить приложение Postman для проверки запросов - оно Вам пригодится ещё не раз.
Для начала напишите, на какой сервер отправляете запрос, и я проверю его в своём Postman'е. Также сохраните себе вот эту ссылку: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ - очень полезная штука для обработки JSON-запросов.

Comment: @ПавелСумароков Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ! Сервер меня просили не скидывать, это прям очень нужно? Postman у меня есть, уже проверял, всё работает, в самом Postman'е я вытаскивать данные научился. Проблема в том, чтобы все это дело перенести в код)

Comment: @ПавелСумароков Но там еще прикол в том, что параметры отправляются в JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результаты успешного запроса из Postman'а копируйте и вставляйте в http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, полученные файлы при необходимости корректируйте и вставляйте в проект Android Studio в директорию (package) с именем model - имя необязательно, просто так традиционно устоялось. После этого пишете два модуля: фабрику и сервис, и кладёте их в проекте в директорию network.

Код фабрики:

```
//Импортируем необходимые классы
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

//Объявляем фабрику - только статичные поля и методы
public class ApiFactory {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "https://your_api_address";

    static Retrofit buildRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static ApiService getService() {
        return buildRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Код сервиса (с учётом запроса POST и входных параметров логин и пароль):

```
//Импортируйте получившиеся у Вас в JSON-POJO модели
//В данном случае Вы должны назвать свою модель AccessToken
import com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.model.AccessToken;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;

public interface ApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("auth/login") //путь вашего сервиса к авторизации
        Call<AccessToken> getToken(
        @Query("login") String login,
        @Query("password") String password);
}
```

В основной части Вашего приложения для получения токена в ответ на логин и пароль Вы прописываете примерно так (с учётом того, как у Вас названы переменные, классы и т.д.):

```
private void getToken() {
    Call<AccessToken> call = ApiFactory.getService().getToken(EMAIL, PASSWORD);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //Тут Вы просто сохраняете токен для дальнейшего использования
                MainActivity.token = response.body().getData().getToken();
                MainActivity.tokenAcquired = true;
                Log.d("myLogs", token);
                getTasks();
            } else {
                MainActivity.token = "";
                MainActivity.tokenAcquired = false;
                Log.d("myLogs", ErrorUtils.errorMessage(response));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {}
    });
}
```

Класс ErrorUtils (не обязательно, только для распарсивания ошибки):

```
package com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.network;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Locale;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ErrorUtils {

    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Код HTTP: %d\nОшибка: %s\nКод ошибки: %d";

    private static APIError parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter =
                ApiFactory.buildRetrofit()
                        .responseBodyConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);
        APIError error;
        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new APIError();
        }

        return error;
    }

    public static String errorMessage(Response<?> response) {
        try {
            APIError error = parseError(response);
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ERROR_MESSAGE, response.code(), error.message(), error.status());
        } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ERROR_MESSAGE, response.code(), "NULL", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс ApiError

```
package com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.network;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class APIError {

    @SerializedName("httpStatus")
    private int statusCode;
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String message;

    public APIError() {
    }

    public int status() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String message() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Ну вот Вам для начала информация для размышления. com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME - это название Вашего проекта, указанное в заголовках java-модулей. Пока разбирайтесь и спокойной ночи. Если возникнут какие-то вопросы - задавайте, но отвечу уже завтра. Заранее простите, если какие-то опечатки в коде будут. Удачной работы!

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! :)

Comment: У Вас всё получилось?

Comment: Да, немного еще поразбирался и всё вышло. Еще раз спасибо! Тут на сайте есть какие-то плюсики, или им подобные способы сказать "спасибо"?)

Comment: Поставьте галочку на ответ. Вам начислятся баллы